# Do we know if Unearthed Arcana will eventually be compiled or distributed in books?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana

I understand that these are free play-test supplements from WOTC, but does any body know if any of this is gonna eventually be either collected in to one major book or distributed in various future D&D 5e supplements?

Answer (score 11):

Only the designers can possibly know this. However, the rest of us have some clues. Every Unearthed Arcana article includes this sentence in its disclaimer:

> If we decide
>   to make this material official, 
>   it
>   will
>   be
>   refined based on your feedback, and then it
>   will
>   appear 
>   in a 
>   D&D 
>   book.

So, Unearthed Arcana will be published if "we" (the designers) decide to make it official.

Another clue we have is that some Unearthed Arcana articles have already been published. The Swashbuckler and the Storm Sorcerer from [this](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/unearthed-arcana-waterborne-adventures) article both appeared in the *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, albeit with some changes.

Given that, to date, these are the only Unearthed Arcana elements that have been published, it is likely that some Unearthed Arcana will be published, and some won't be. Also, given that the disclaimer mentions UA being refined based on feedback, and given the changes made to Storm Sorcerer, we can't assume that any UA will be published exactly as it was originally released.

Comment: Were there any changes between the UA & the published version?

Comment: @Adeptus Good point, there were indeed.